# Should I process a JSON in the frontend or Backend, which is faster?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, data-structures

I am getting a response from an API as a json response. 
I am coding in python for backend.

The frontend team needs information from the raw json response for populating a UI so we have to order the json and make it more easier for them to fetch information.

Now I can order the json in a specific format and push to the frontend team or I can pass the raw json response*to the frontend team and let them handle ordering the json and further use for their UI.

Remember my json file size is *15MB*.

Which is faster and a better design principle?

Process in the backend then push to frontend or process in the frontend?

Comment: In my opinion, processing on server is better in your case because of size and lenght of data, as usually servers give much better performance than the browsers in pc.

Comment: Ideally, the front end simply consumes the API responses. Given the UI will be running on other people's computers (which may be weak and slow), you don't want to offload data munging to the client side cos it can lead to a slow and unpleasant experience in your webapp. The response from the backend should be more or less in the format needed for the front end. Ideally, front end shouldn't be doing much (if any) real data processing, that should be done server side

Comment: 15MB is kind of a lot, I would do it on the backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally if the file size is 15 mb it will be loaded to the browsers memory which will make it slow, I would suggest to do the operation in backend only.

You can also go through this link for reference.
[Difference Between python and Javascript and what to use](https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/python-vs-javascript/)

1. One important aspect is that JavaScript is difficult to debug. You
   might notice that despite your code being error-free, the program
   won’t work (fail silently).

Answer (score 4):

It's always better to process the data in backend itself.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to perform this on the backend, some key reasons I would suggest this is:

- Processing on mobile devices leads to massive battery drain
- If your frontend is web, javascript will block while the processing is occurring (which could lead to bad experiences)
- Server response can be cached to speed up response times and lower duplicate processing
- Your backend language may be able to perform the task more optimally then the frontend device can

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, there are quite a few good reasons to prefer processing on the back end:

- if you can remove all unnecessary data from the JSON being sent to the front-end, it will reduce load on the end-user device both in terms of transfer but also in parsing time
- it may be possible to cache the remote API call, so you don't need to make as many calls out to the remote APIs (which will usually be very slow compared to cache retrieval). You can also potentially cache the after-processing data, so you can just serve that up repeatedly
- You can detect errors that happen in processing the JSON, whereas that is less visible if it is happening on the client device

One other big advantage to processing the API response on the back-end is that you can choose the structure you send to the front end. That way, if the API you are consuming changes over time (or you change which service you're using to retrieve data) you can handle that change on the back end without it ever affecting the front-end code.